# Linux scp command not working with a specified port

Tags: linux, scp, remote-server

I'm using

```
 scp -r -P 10122 -i /home/gndp/.ssh/openssh.puk gndp@localserver.com:~/folder/subfolder gndp@192.168.1.197:/home/gndp/
```

it says:

```
ssh: connect to host "localhost" port 22: Connection refused
```

192.168.1.197 connects to remote website

am i missing something?

i've also tried

```
scp -r -P10122 -i /home/gndp/.ssh/openssh.puk gndp@localserver.com:~/folder/subfolder gndp@192.168.1.197:/home/gndp/
```

with same error

Comment: Is dev.kaar-ma.com running an SSH server and have you made sure there isn't a firewall between you and it?

Comment: yes, it is but n no firewall
my problem got solved by restarting putty and entering same command

Comment: generally, i would use `rsync` and some entries in my `.ssh/config`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

actually what solved my problem was removing "gndp@localhost.com:" and running the command as:

```
scp -r -P 10122 -i /home/gndp/.ssh/openssh.puk ~/folder/subfolder gndp@192.168.1.197:/home/gndp/
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the simple quote like '-P 10122' in your command